# How to get datetime_difference with django queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have 3 models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'Store_Title', max_length=100)

class OrderExtra(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, verbose_name=u'Order')
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Order(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField(u'Order_Code')
    datetime_begin = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    datetime_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I also have a queryset that returns me all of my stores with count of orders in each store:

```
qs = Order.objects.values('orderextra__store__title').annotate(orders_count=Count('code'))
```

As a result I get:

```
qs[0] = {'orders_count': 500, 'orderextra__store__title': u'MyTestStore 1'}
qs[1] = {'orders_count': 200, 'orderextra__store__title': u'MyTestStore 2'}
```

What I want is an orm queryset or native sql query for doing something like this:

For `'MyTestStore 1'` there are `500` orders, each of that orders has datetime_begin and datetime_end.
For each of that `500` orders I want to calculate difference: `diff = datetime_end - datetime_begin`.
As a result I will get `500` diff's.
Next step is to calculate this: `diff1 + diff2 + diff3 + diff500 / 500` (get average from all diff's).
And as final result of queryset I want to get:

```
qs[0] = {'orders_average_diff': 7.3 (minutes), 'orderextra__store__title': u'MyTestStore 1'}
qs[1] = {'orders_average_diff': 4.2 (minutes), 'orderextra__store__title': u'MyTestStore 2'}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this if this gives correct result (result may be in different format) for you

I am not sure btw :)

```
z = {}
q1 = OrderExtra.objects.all()
for q in q1:
  # Get time difference in minutes for this order
  diff = q.order.datetime_end - q.order.datetime_begin
  diffm = diff.seconds / 60
  #check if store is already updated to z
  check = z.get(q.store.title, 'error')
  # if NOT add storeName as key and c= Counter, a = Avg date-time diff
  if check == 'error':
    z.update({q.store.title:{'c':1, 'd':diffm, 'a': diffm}})
  # If Available calculate avg with counter and total diff
  else:
    avgm = (( diffm + z[q.store.title]['d'] ) // (z[q.store.title]['c'] + 1))
    z[q.store.title]['a'] = avgm 
    z[q.store.title]['d'] = diffm + z[q.store.title]['d'] 
    z[q.store.title]['c'] =  z[q.store.title]['c'] + 1
```